# Updating a struct column in bigquery

Tags: sql, struct, google-bigquery, nested

I have a table with 1 normal mode column `id` and a struct(record, repeated) column `details`.
The details column has `country` and `name` column nested inside that.

I have five records inside the details column.

```
country name
UK      sarah
IND     carter
Itay    marie
France  john
peru    christy
```

I am using the below query to update the value of a single record.

```
update 
info_table
set value=array(
    select as struct * replace('US' as country)) from unnest(details)
    where name='sarah'
)
where id=100
```

This updates the country value from UK to US successfully, however, this does remove the rest of the 4 records.

I need a query to update the struct fields without messing up the other records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
UPDATE info_table
SET details = (
  SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT
      IF(name = 'sarah', 'US', country) AS country,
      name
    FROM UNNEST(details)
  )
)
WHERE id = 100
```

Comment: Can you explain what this part actually doing, 
select array(select as struct). If you don't mind

Comment: each element in the unnested array, this statement creates a new struct. The struct has two fields:
country: If the name field is equal to 'sarah', it assigns the value 'US' to country; otherwise, it assigns the value of the country field from the original array element.
name: This field simply takes the name field's value from the original array element.